# Cannot repeat ffmpeg commnad in one bash script

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have this simple bash script for ffmpeg conversion. If there is only one call for ffmpeg, script works well. If there are 2 or more calls, only the last call for ffmpeg is successfull. For previous calls there is the error: unable to find suitable output format for /var/.../.../.jpg : Invalid argumentlic_html. It seems to me it is needed to call ffmpeg by different way. Any idea?

```
#!/bin/bas
ffmpeg -y -i "http://xx/22.m3u8" -qscale:v 2 -vframes 1 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: text='%{localtime}': fontsize=20: fontcolor=white@0.9: x=20: y=20: box=1: boxcolor=red@0.2" /var/xxx/22.jpg
ffmpeg -y -i "http://xx/23.m3u8" -qscale:v 2 -vframes 1 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: text='%{localtime}': fontsize=20: fontcolor=white@0.9: x=20: y=20: box=1: boxcolor=red@0.2" /var/xxx/23.jpg
```

Comment: If the script has been pasted accurately, remove `-vf`. The commands are malformed. But since you say the last command works,  I guess the paste isn't correct.

Comment: Does the shebang line really say `#!/bin/bas`?

Comment: Yes, I tried to make the code more simple and put away its drawtext part. It works if there is only one command. It works with or without #!/bin/bas

Comment: Add `-report` to both commands and run script. Share the two report files.

Comment: if MS windows was involved (anywhere) in touching your script file, run `cat -vet myScript.sh` and if you see `^M$` at the end of lines, then `dos2unix myScript.sh`. AND (for crying out loud), fix your she-bang line to `#!/bin/bash` ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: Solved. Thank you very much Shellter. It was MS windows.